# Div not showing background-color

Tags: html, css, background-color

`.wrap`  div is supposed to have a light orange background but its showing up as white. I've tried using `overflow:hidden` on `.wrap` (and on `.banner` when I got desperate) but I have no clue whats going on.

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> My Home Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="banner">
        <h1> Welcome!<span style="color:#FF009D">•‌</span><span style="color:#12E00B">•‌</span><span style="color:#FF9D00">•‌</span> </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap">

        <div class="item">
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/maxxchewning">
                <img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/HrkZQ3EOmFQ/hqdefault.jpg" />
                <div class="button"></div>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/Christianguzmanfitne">
                <img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/zsD_7hkfEwY/hqdefault.jpg" />
                <div class="button"></div>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/PhysiquesOfGreatness">
                <img src="http://v017o.popscreen.com/VzFBeVBjMHhpRWMx_o_new-physiques-of-greatness-intro-25.jpg" />
                <div class="button"></div>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <a href="https://www.reddit.com">
                <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/459083822470946816/VGv0AGio.png" />
                <div class="button"></div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <a href="https://www.ebay.com">
                <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/471350614132129793/NCDCFXva.jpeg" />
                <div class="button"></div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com">
                <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/3513354941/24aaffa670e634a7da9a087bfa83abe6_400x400.png" />
                <div class="button"></div>
            </a>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="footer"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
body {       
        margin-top:-3px;
}
.banner {
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    background-color: rgba(64, 201, 255, .5);
    margin-left:-10px;
}

h1 { 
    font-size:80px;
    margin-left:30px;
    font-family:Futura;
    line-height:120px;
    color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
    width:100%;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    padding-top:30px;

}
h1:hover { 
    font-size:80px;
    font-family:Futura;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(64, 201, 255,0.9);
    width:100%;
    padding-top:30px;
}

}
.wrap { 
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 190, 77, 1);
    height:750px;
    margin-right:0px;
}
.item {
    float:left;
    width:25%;
    padding:10px;
    margin-left: 60px;

}

.item img {
    width:100%;
    padding-top:10px;
    max-height:200px;
    opacity:1;
}
.item img:hover {
    opacity:.4;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    -moz-transform:    scale(1.2);
    -o-transform:      scale(1.2);
    -ms-transform:     scale(1.2);
}

.button {
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    height:50px;
    width:100%;
    border-bottom-right-radius:.5em;
    border-bottom-left-radius:.5em;    
    transition: background-color 0.3s linear;     
}
.item:hover .button{
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0)

}
```

Comment: you can provide jsfiddle of the same code so that we can see output

Comment: You have an extra `}` at the end of your `h1:hover` rule.

Comment: you have wrong HTML code too. <div class="footer"></footer>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should be using `overflow:hidden` on `.wrap` because you are floating divs (or a clearfix), but your issue was an extra `}`

```
h1:hover { 
  font-size:80px;
  font-family:Futura;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(64, 201, 255,0.9);
  width:100%;
  padding-top:30px;
}

} <------------- remove

.wrap { 
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 190, 77, 1);
  height:750px;
  margin-right:0px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/doy77t8p/)

Answer (score 0):

According to  the standard, whenever you have an element that has some floated elements inside it, the element collapses to zero height. This is what's happened to your wrap div since items are floated inside it. To solve the issue you can either use `overflow:auto` to class `wrap` or place a div after all items which has `clear:both` as its property. This div should have no content inside:

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is issue in , rather than everything is fine.

```
h1:hover {
    font-size:80px;
    font-family:Futura;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(64, 201, 255,0.9);
    width:100%;
    padding-top:30px;
}

/*} */  --- this is extra bracket you given which have an issue.
.wrap {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 190, 77, 1);
    height:750px;
    margin-right:0px;
}
```

This is whole html .

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> My Home Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <style >
        body {
        margin-top:-3px;
}
.banner {
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    background-color: rgba(64, 201, 255, .5);
    margin-left:-10px;
}

h1 {
    font-size:80px;
    margin-left:30px;
    font-family:Futura;
    line-height:120px;
    color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
    width:100%;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    padding-top:30px;

}
h1:hover {
    font-size:80px;
    font-family:Futura;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(64, 201, 255,0.9);
    width:100%;
    padding-top:30px;
}

/*}*/
.wrap {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 190, 77, 1);
    height:750px;
    margin-right:0px;
}
.item {
    float:left;
    width:25%;
    padding:10px;
    margin-left: 60px;

}

.item img {
    width:100%;
    padding-top:10px;
    max-height:200px;
    opacity:1;
}
.item img:hover {
    opacity:.4;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    -moz-transform:    scale(1.2);
    -o-transform:      scale(1.2);
    -ms-transform:     scale(1.2);
}

.button {
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    height:50px;
    width:100%;
    border-bottom-right-radius:.5em;
    border-bottom-left-radius:.5em;
    transition: background-color 0.3s linear;
}
.item:hover .button{
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0)

}
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="banner">
        <h1> Welcome!<span style="color:#FF009D">•‌</span><span style="color:#12E00B">•‌</span><span style="color:#FF9D00">•‌</span> </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap">

        <div class="item">
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/maxxchewning">
                <img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/HrkZQ3EOmFQ/hqdefault.jpg" />
                <div class="button"></div>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/Christianguzmanfitne">
                <img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/zsD_7hkfEwY/hqdefault.jpg" />
                <div class="button"></div>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/PhysiquesOfGreatness">
                <img src="http://v017o.popscreen.com/VzFBeVBjMHhpRWMx_o_new-physiques-of-greatness-intro-25.jpg" />
                <div class="button"></div>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <a href="https://www.reddit.com">
                <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/459083822470946816/VGv0AGio.png" />
                <div class="button"></div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <a href="https://www.ebay.com">
                <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/471350614132129793/NCDCFXva.jpeg" />
                <div class="button"></div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com">
                <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/3513354941/24aaffa670e634a7da9a087bfa83abe6_400x400.png" />
                <div class="button"></div>
            </a>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="footer"></div>
</body>

</html>
```